# Jquery datatables column search case unsensitive

Tags: jquery, datatables, case-insensitive

this is my scenario:
I have a datatable that I initialize in this way:

```
invoicesDataTable = $('#invoicesDataTable').DataTable({

                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                searchDelay: 1000,
                search: {
                    caseInsensitive: true
                },
                ajax: {
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '{!! route("admin.invoice.filterData") !!}',
                    dataSrc: function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                    }
                },
//              aLengthMenu: [ [ 50, 100, 150, 200, -1 ], [ 50, 100, 150, 200, 'All' ] ],
                columns: [
                    {data: 'document_number', name: 'invoices.document_number', orderable: false},
                    {data: 'document_type', name: 'invoices.document_type', orderable: false},
                    {data: 'tax_regime', name: 'invoices.tax_regime', orderable: false},
                    {data: 'auction_id', name: 'auctions.auction_id', orderable: false},
                    {data: 'business_name', name: 'customers.business_name', orderable: false},
                    {data: 'total_amount', name: 'invoices.total_amount', orderable: false},
                    {data: 'datetime_invoice', name: 'invoices.datetime_invoice', orderable: false},
                    {data: 'actions', name: 'actions', orderable: false, searchable: false}
                ],
            });
```

After initialization I add search on each column in this way:

```
$('#invoicesDataTable thead th').each(function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html('<input type="text" style="width:100%;" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
        });

        invoicesDataTable.columns().every(function () {
            var that = this;
            $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change', function () {
                if (that.search() !== this.value)
                    that.search(this.value, false, true, true).draw();
            });
        });
```

It works correctly except for case insensitive search. If I have a column with value like "John" and I search for "john" it doesn't show to me the row with "John". There is a way to make it works?
(The global search works perfectly in case insensitive way)

Comment: Your code works fine, see https://jsfiddle.net/aL3f4w9n/

Answer (score 0):

Do your comparison all in uppercase or lower case.

*Eg.:*

```
 if (that.search().toLowerCase() !== this.value.toLowerCase())
```

or

```
 if (that.search().toUpperCase() !== this.value.toUpperCase())
```

Comment: That is not correct answer, this line only makes sure that the value in the text box changed.

Answer (score 0):

That is the issue of sql side. SQL basically performs case sensitive search.
Use 'ILIKE' if sql or postgres is used.

Reference: [I referred here to solve the same issue](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/23109/please-pass-the-search-caseinsensitive-over-to-the-server-side-processing)

Answer (score 0):

Check your [database collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html). It can affect case sensitive searches.